# Blank screen with windows and cursor

Tags: windows-10

### The Problem

For some odd reason this just happened where when I log into **Windows** with my user account I have just a blank screen with some windows and cursor.

[image]

### What Happened and My Workaround

I was forced to do a **Windows Update** then sometime afterwards my screen went completely blank but I can access the Task Manager and run apps and open stuff through it.

### What I've tried

I've tried doing a system restore, full AV scanning (no viruses found), and booted in safe mode but the blank screen loads there too.

### Question

I need help getting this problem fixed or some guidance for further troubleshooting at least.

### Other Information

I have third party software installed that allows me to change the **Windows 10** start menu to look more like older versions of **Windows**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Task Manager **File** | **Run new task** type **cmd** for and press **Enter** command prompt and then run the below commands to enable the local administrator account and give it a password.

```
NET USER administrator /active:yes
NET USER administrator <Type In Password Here>
```

Now run the `SHUTDOWN -L` to log out of the corrupt account and log onto the administrator account with that same password you just created and then complete the below.

> ### [Repair the corrupt user profile registry key](https://www.easeus.com/todo-backup-resource/fix-a-corrupted-user-profile-windows-10.html)
>
> **Step 1.** Open the Windows 10 **Registry Editor** by typing **regedit** in the Search box.
>
> **Step 2.** When Registry Editor launches, navigate to the following key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`.
>
> **Step 3**. Click each `S-1-5` folder and double-click the **ProfileImagePath** entry to find out which user account it relates to. (If your folder name ends with `.bak` or `.ba` follow Microsoft’s
>   instructions to rename them).
>
> [image]
>
> **Step 4.** Once you have determined where is the corrupt user profile(and it doesn’t have a `.bak` ending), double-click
>   **RefCount** and change the Value data to **0** and click **OK**. If this value isn’t available, you might have to create it manually.
>
> **Step 5.** Now double-click on **State**, make sure the Value data is again **0** and click **OK**.
>
> [image]
>
> **Step 6.** Close **Registry Editor** and restart your PC.

Lastly, disable the local admin account to the state it was in before you enabled it if applicable

```
NET USER administrator /active:no
```

Comment: That article doesn't say to enable hidden Admin account.

Comment: @Biswapriyo Yes, sorry.... actually that article and it's steps are just one part of the process. The detail not quote referenced from that article in this particular case was used in conjunction with those outlined and referenced steps to resolve. There was a big comment chat the OP and I had on it so at the end those were removed and I added to an answer the basic steps used to fully resolve the problem. It is not real clear but the referenced post is like step #4 or #5 in this instance so again I just outlined the steps taken to resolve steps by step.

Comment: They had no other account to log onto at this machine and they could not get control panel to open with the rundll command line either, so the only way was to set the admin password and enable it via command line and then log onto the admin account. They also tried safe mode with the other one account and they couldn't get it to load or anything accessible there either. @Biswapriyo

Comment: Basically they only thing that was accessible until that admin account was enabled and used was command line and we have to work with whatever worked and that's what worked in that order too I suppose.